# splunk regex to find and count URL query strings

Tags: regex, set, splunk

I have a Splunk instance collecting web traffic data, and would like to find a list of unique query strings from a known URL, and create a count of each.

Each URL has a query string attached in this format:

```
httx://www.sitename.com?v=123456&timestamp=1234456456458
httx://www.sitename.com?v=999999&timestamp=1234456456602
httx://www.sitename.com?v=123456&timestamp=1234456457001
httx://www.sitename.com?v=459743&timestamp=1234456457365
httx://www.sitename.com?v=010101&timestamp=1234456458777
```

What I'm hoping to get is a count of each 'v' value, without knowing ahead of time what values exist (but I do know they are numberical and always 6 digits) so I assume I'll need regex.

I'm thinking it will look something like this?

```
index=URLData sourcetype =* www.sitename.com "v=" | rex "(?P<stringdata>.+)(?v=:\d{6}):?" | count by stringdata
```

Comment: Either `(?<stringdata>[^&]+)(?<v>\d{6})` or `(?<stringdata>[^?&]+)(?<v>\d{6})` or `(?<stringdata>[^&]+)[?]v=(?<v>\d{6})`.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work.  Could it be because the URL contains the '?'.  Does it need to be escaped to work with sed?

Comment: If you use it inside a character class, you do not need to escape the `?`. However, in sed, you cannot use named captures. Just use `([^&]+)[?]v=([0-9]{6})`, or `([^&]+)[?]v=([0-9]\{6\})`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
index=scratch www.sitename.com "v=" | rex "v=(?P<stringdata>\d+)"|stats count by stringdata
```

Change index to suit yours